# how to print the value before it was changed?(google script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

If the value changes while using Google Script, I want to record the change in the cell next to it. Trigger is tested, but only the value after the change is saved, not the value before the change. Where do I need to fix to get the value before the change?

```
function onEdit1()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "sheet1") //"order data" is the name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var aCol = headers[0].indexOf("A") + 1;
    var usdCol = headers[0].indexOf("USD") + 1;
    var rmbCol = headers[0].indexOf("RMB") + 1;
    
    var changedData = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, usdCol).getValues();
    var logData = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, aCol).getValues();
    
    if (aCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == usdCol)
    {
      if (!sheet.getRange(rowIndex, aCol).isBlank())
      {
        sheet.getRange(rowIndex, aCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "yyyy-MM-dd") + "에 " + changedData + "(으)로 변경" + "/" + logData);
      }else{
        logData = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "yyyy-MM-dd") + "에 " + changedData + "(으)로 변경됨" + " / ";
        // sheet.getRange(rowIndex, aCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "yyyy-MM-dd") + "에 " + changedData + "(으)로 변경됨" + " / ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although about `Where do I need to fix to get the value before the change?`, I could correctly understand, for example, how about using `oldValue` of the event object of OnEdit trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) But, I'm not sure whether this is included in the direction you expect. I apologize for this.

Comment: thanks.. for example, if cell's value was 1(last value). Update value 1(last) to 2(now). Then I want get value 1(last) for write record...
If i use 'oldValue' then it means value 1(before update)?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a cell before it changes you could use the on edit trigger.

If a single cell is edited and, the event object might included `value` and `oldValue` properties.

The following is a very simple example that logs the old value to the cell to the right of the edited cell.

```
function onEdite(e){
   if(e.oldValue) e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.oldValue);
}
```

- The `value` property will be `undefined` if the cell is cleared.
- The `oldValue` property will be `undefined` if the cell was blank
- Both properties will be `undefined` if multiple cells were edited (`range` property includes more than one cell)